# Как найти индекс элемента в массиве объектов?

Tags: javascript

Для поиска индекса элемента в массиве можно использовать методы  `indexOf` (для первого вхождения) и `lastIndexOf` (для последнего вхождения).

А как можно найти индекс в массиве объектов? Например индекс при первом вхождении нужного объекта?

Например есть массив объектов:

```
let inputArr = [{name:'bruce', age:40, city:'gotham'},
                {name:'barry', age:25, city:'fallville'},
                {name:'diana', age:30, city:'themyscira'}
               ];
```

Как получить индекс, где в свойстве `name` значение  `barry`? Если писать так:

```
inputArr.indexOf('barry');
```

то выведет `-1`, а ожидаемое значение — `1`. Может циклом перебирать все значения? Может есть простые способы?

---

<sub>orig post https://stackoverflow.com/q/8668174/6104996</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Варианты:

1. Использовать **[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)**, которая в качестве параметра принимает `callback` функцию, в которой можно указать условия.

   Её можно использовать для поиска непримитивных типов (в т.ч. объектов), а также где можно/нужно задать более сложные условия, нежели просто значение. Если элемент не найден — возвращается `-1`.

   ```
   let searchName = 'barry';
   let index = inputArr.findIndex(el => el.name === searchName);
   ```

   Кстати, плюс этого метода: найдя нужный элемент — итерация по массиву прекращается. То есть если массив из 100 элементов и найден индекс 3, то остальные 97 итераций не происходят.

---

2. Вариант с **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** для массива. В чём идея:

   - Пробежаться с помощью `map`, выбрав в массив нужные значения по указанному свойству
   - Уже **к этому** массиву и применять `indexOf`

   Пример:

   ```
   let searchName = 'barry';
   let index = inputArr.map(el => el.name).indexOf(searchName);
   ```

   **Недостаток**:  `map` создает целый массив, в котором лежат эдементы с нужным `property`. Поэтому если в массиве, например 1000 элементов, то может сказаться на производительности.

   **Плюс**: в отличие от `findIndex` - `map` поддерживают больше браузеров, т.к. это более старый метод для работы с массивами

---

3. Для немодерновых браузеров, которые не умеют в `findIndex`, например *IE8 (9,10,11)*, придется делать цикл. **Одно замечание**: нужно делать не цикл `for...in`, а обычный `for`, чтобы в любой момент при нахождении элемента можно было сразу прервать цикл, чтобы не работал вхолостую

   ```
   function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, property, searchTerm) {
       for(let i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
           if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) 
               return i;
       }

       return -1;
   }

   let index = arrayObjectIndexOf(inputArr, 'name', searchName);
   console.log(index);
   ```

---

4. Если интересуют библиотеки, то в **[underscore.js library](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex)**, есть метод `_.findIndex`

   ```
   var index = _.findIndex(inputArr, {name:searchName}) // 1
   ```

   Можно задать несколько условий (как и при использовании `findIndex`), например:

   ```
   let inputArr = [{a:1}, {a:2, c:10}, {a:3}, {a:2, c:12}, {a:2, c:8}];
   let cond = {a:2,c:12};
   var index = _.findIndex(inputArr, cond)
   console.log(index); // 3
   ```